# Android OnPOst excute is not called

Tags: java, android

I have an async task. It runs a sql query.It should go to the onPostExecute automatically, but it does not always go there. THere is no exception.The logs are also fine.

```
class QueryDbTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {
protected Cursor doInBackground(String... params) {
.... 
//sql query
try {
         cur=activityObject.execSQL(Query);

   }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printstacktrace
}
return cur;}
protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {   
}
```

Under what conditions onPostExecute would not be called?

i debugged and found that it was not reaching onPost Execute

Can two async task simulataneoulsy?

Comment: What you are doing in onPostExecute???

Comment: How do you know it's not called? If you debug it, what is happening after doInBackground? What will be executed?

Comment: So you don't do anything in the onPostExecute method? Not even a super call? And is "return cur" line in doInBackground called?

Comment: Yes .Retuen statement is there in doinbackground

Comment: could you post the code in your onPostExecute() method? And please check if onCancelled() is not called.

Comment: can 2 async task run at same time....async tasks are basically threads which can modify ui thread right?

Comment: AsyncTasks consist of a background thread and 3 (I guess 3) handlers that run on the UI thread: OnPreExecute, onProgressChanged and OnPostExecute. Is there absolutely nothing in your onPostExecute? In that case of course you cant debug it.

Comment: And yes, many asyncTasks can run at the same time

Comment: its not reaching onpostexecute :(

Comment: Allright, I will ask it one last time: what is in your onPostExecute method? Is onCanceled getting called?

Comment: NO onCancelled is not getting called anywhere,,,in onPOstExecute i am iterating the cursor ..setting values

Comment: oh...is there an @Override annotation on onPostExecute()?

Answer (score 1):

`onPostExecute()` would not be called if `doInBackground()` never finished or if the task was interrupted/cancelled in which case `onCancelled()` would be called.

Comment: Can 2 asyc task run simultaneously?

Comment: Of course they can and should. You do not need more than one core for that, it is called multi TASKing after all.

Comment: Actually, they do not unless you force them to.  Pre 3.0 they ran serially.  In 3.0 they made them run in parallel.  For 4.0+ they switched it back.  I asked that very question during a live developer hangout and straight from their mouths, "We changed it back because it broke a lot of stuff."

Comment: ok then i know why its not always going......   in my onresume i am calling this async task...but at the end of the onResume i am calling another async task based on some conditions. So when those conditions are fulfilled the 2nd async task starts before the first is completed. Can that be the case? i better test this scenario

Comment: It depends on the version of the OS.  In the olden days :) calling an AsyncTask while one was running would cancel the first.  Starting with version ??? (2.2 I think) they should just execute serially.

Answer (score -1):

You have to put an @Override annotation to onPostExecute() to be called

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
....
}
```